# Meaning of " It can be [noun or adjective]"

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

What is the meaning of "It can be false" and " It can be true." ?
How to interpret meaning when sentence structure is "Subject + can + be + Noun(or adjective )." ?

I am non-native speaker. Please explain.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The **can** here means: [To be possible, usually with be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can#Etymology_1).

It can be false = It is possible for it to be false.